# WCF Authentification Android App - Maui WCF Webservice Basic

Tags: android, authentication, wcf

Good Morning,

im confused about the Authentification Error on my App. It works fine on App for Windows.

On Android the Error is following:
Clientauthentificationscheme "Basic" not authorizt. Basic realm="" received.

Somewhere i read about encoding the User Password, but i dont get it. Help appreciated.

```
var basicHttpBinding = new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportCredentialOnly);
basicHttpBinding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Basic;
NetworkCredential netCred = new NetworkCredential("*USERNAME*", "*PASSWORD*");
clientCredentials.UserName.UserName = netCred.UserName;
clientCredentials.UserName.Password = netCred.Password;

serviceEndpoint.Binding = basicHttpBinding;
serviceEndpoint.Address = new EndpointAddress("WEBSERVICEURL....");
```

usesCleartextTrafic="True" is set to true.

Thanks!

Comment: At the moment I deduce that it might be an issue with the security certificate. There is a mmc console setting certificate on Microsoft, which may need to be set separately on Android. Specific solutions require more information from you.